# Undefined Index .. But I have done the same thing in short..then running

Tags: php

I am making online examination.. the data are passing from page to examination page. but the value of radio button is not passing from examination page to result page. I have checked that the course name and subject names are passing. I have added the timer section. Which is working good. The value of radio button inside the while is not passing to result..

**EXAM CODE**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>EXAM</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?PHP
 //$i=1;
 $j=1;
 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "online_exam";
 $server = "127.0.0.1";
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database);
 if ($db_found)
 { session_start();
   $i=$_SESSION['$i'];
   $sub = $_SESSION['$sub'];
  /*if(isset($_POST['b_subject']))
    {
       $selected_button=$_POST['subject'];
       if($selected_button=='subject1')
            $_SESSION['$sub']= "GK";
       else if($selected_button=='subject2')
            $_SESSION['$sub']="math";
        else
            print "error";
    }*/
     if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
           $selected_button=$_POST['subject'];
  }
  else
  {
           $selected_button="default button";
  }
 while($j<$i)
    {     
      if($selected_button=='subject'.$j)
            $s= $sub[$j];
     $j++;
    }
 //print $_SESSION['$sub'];
 //print $selected_button;  
//print $_SESSION['$cour'];
//print 
// //assign $_SESSION['array'] to $array
 //print $sub[1];   
 /* foreach($sub as $value) {
     print $value; //print $array contents
  }*/


      $c = $_SESSION['$cour'];
  //$s = $_SESSION['$sub'];
  $SQL = "SELECT ques FROM ques_ans WHERE course='$c' AND subj='$s'";
  $result = mysql_query($SQL);
  echo '<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action="result_a.php" >';
  while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
    {
         print $db_field['ques']."<BR>";
?>

         <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques<?PHP echo $i;?>' value= '1'>YES
         <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques<?PHP echo $i;?>' value= '0'>NO
         <br>

<?PHP           
          $i++;         
    }
  $_SESSION['$i']= $i;
  //$_SESSION['ques'] = $que;
  $_SESSION['$sub'] = $s;  
  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></FORM>';   
  mysql_close($db_handle);
}
$targetDate = time()+(330*60) + (1*30);
$actualDate = time()+(330*60);
$secondsDiff = $targetDate - $actualDate;
$remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
$remainingHour    = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24))/60/60);
$remainingMinutes = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
$remainingSeconds = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinutes*60));
?>
<h1>Time Left</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">  
var hours = <?php echo $remainingHour; ?>  
var minutes = <?php echo $remainingMinutes; ?>  
var seconds = <?php echo $remainingSeconds; ?> 
function setCountDown ()
{
seconds--;
if (seconds < 0){
  minutes--;
  seconds = 59
}
if (minutes < 0){
  hours--;
  minutes = 59
}
if (hours < 0){
  days--;
  hours = 23
}
document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = hours+" hours : "+minutes+" minutes : "+seconds+" seconds";
SD=window.setTimeout( "setCountDown()", 1000 );
if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
    window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue.");
    window.location = "http://localhost/result_a.php"
} 

}
</script>
<body onload="setCountDown();">
<div id="remain"><?php echo "$remainingHour hours, $remainingMinutes minutes, $remainingSeconds seconds";?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the result the line " $selected_radio = $_POST['ques'.$i];" is showing error that "Undefined index: ques1" , "Undefined index: ques2", ... so on....

**RESULT CODE**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>RESULT</title>
 <body>
 <?PHP
  $i=1;
  $count=0;
 $ans= "";
 session_start();
    //$i=$_SESSION['$i'];
$s=$_SESSION['$sub'];
$c=$_SESSION['$cour'];
//$que[]=$_SESSION['ques'];
//print $c.$s;
 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "online_exam";
 $server = "127.0.0.1";
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database,$db_handle);
 $SQL = "SELECT ans FROM ques_ans WHERE course='$c' AND subj='$s'";
 $result = mysql_query($SQL);
 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
    {
        $selected_radio = $_POST['ques'.$i];
        if ($selected_radio == '1') 
         {
            $ans='1';
         }
        else if ($selected_radio == '0') 
         {
            $ans='0';
         }
         if($ans==$db_field['ans'])
    $count++;
         $i++;
    }
 print $count;
?>
</body>
</html>
</head>
```

Comment: Ok, I do not have the patience to go through that.

Answer (score 0):

you never define `$i =` anything before you attempt to perform `$i++;`, you cannot autoincrement an integer without declaring it's starting value.

Therefore your fields are all actually just

```
name="ques"
```

Without any integer appended to them. Define `$i = 1;` or `$i = 0`; depending on your desire, and this will be resolved.

Comment: of that's my mistake...but still the problem is arising. Actually I want to change the name of the radio buttons for different questions..so I write
  " <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques<?PHP echo $i;?>' value= '1'>YES
   <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='ques<?PHP echo $i;?>' value= '0'>NO"